# YouTube API v3 call works in browser, fails in code

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to make a call from PHP to the YouTube API v3 to get the duration of a video.  I've got my developer key, and have assembled what seems to be a valid URL, based on Google's docs and many other posts on SO:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=rpVJkH7dWsY&part=contentDetails&key={myDeveloperKey}

I can enter this url into a browser, and a correct hunk of stuff comes back.  But when I call it from PHP via `file_get_contents($the_url)`, it fails with a "Connection timed out" error.

I must be doing *something* wrong; any advice?  Thanks!

Comment: OK, I don't really consider this to be an answer/solution, but I've found that I can successfully call this API and retrieve correct data by using cURL instead of file_get_contents.  Maybe the curl approach looks more like a browser call to YT and so sneaks past some validation/testing?  Dunno; advice would still be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing it the exact same way you're describing, with `file_get_contents($the_url)`, and it works fine for me.  The only thing I can think of if it works in a browser but not on your server, is to make sure you're using a different API key that's a server key, where you'd be using a browser key to test from your browser, presumably.  If that's not the issue, I can't think of any other obvious reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: Weird /thanks.  But what's the difference between a "browser key" and a "server key"?  I made my key at console.developers.google.com, and saw only one kind of key there (I think?) -- I followed the semi-obvious path: made a project, created a key, assigned some APIs, etc.  Is there another thing, or kind of thing, to be done here?

Comment: I don't completely understand _why_ there have to be different kinds, just that they seem to break them up between keys for queries that you run in your browser (on the client side), and queries you run from your server code.  Your general process seems fine, just when you click on Create Credentials, Create a New Key, there are 4 options: Server, Browser, Android, and iOS.  You'll probably want one server key and one browser key, from my experience.  Then your JS code and other browser queries can use the browser one, and your php or other server code can use the server code.

Comment: (1) Turns out that the key that I made is a server key, so I'm still confused (despite your help :). (2) The difference between server and browser keys seems to be that server keys can whitelist addresses, and browser keys can whitelist referrers / websites.  In any case, I seem to be in some weird corner situation, but I have something that works, so I'm declaring victory and moving on...  Thanks!